# How to wait to execute await statement jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that asynchronously loads configuration from external config server and awaits for the response, i have mocked the response object with global.fetch, however my console statement is not reached, test skip executing statements after await call. Below the line after await statement is not logged. How to make jest to wait the promise is resolved?

**StyleWrapper.tsx**

```
const StyleWrapper: FC = (props) => {
  let async arrangeTiles = async() => {
    const styleConf = await StyleWrapperHelper.getStyleConfig();
    console.log(styleConf.defaultStyleName); // This line not executed during test!!!
  };
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ arrangeTiles }}>
      <div id="cnplStyleWrapper">{props.children}</div>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

**StyleWrapper.test.tsx**

```
test('Test Load style configuration', () => {

   global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
   Promise.resolve({
            json: () => Promise.resolve({"maxNumberOfTiles":20, "defaultStyleName": "CNPLCore"}),
        })
      ) as jest.Mock;

   const styleWrapper = mount(<StyleWrapper />);
   styleWrapper.update();
      
   expect(container.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: You have a synchronous function using the `await` keyword: that is a syntax error.

Comment: That is a typo, corrected in the original question. the point is when testcase run not waiting to execute await statement it just skipping rest of code